# How to run main(String [] args) from another class (SendMail)

Tags: java, android

I am using SendMail which allows me to send an email message.

If I right click the class and choose *Run 'SendMail().main'*, then the class compiles and correctly runs. It sends me an email.

How can I run SendMail().main from another class?

What I've tried:

1. Adding an activity form to SendMail, and tried initializing with intent from another class.

Code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(anotherClass.this, SendMail.class));
```

2. Tell anotherClass to run a void on SendMail.

anotherClass Code:

```
public void loginAs()
{
SendMail class2 = new SendMail();
class2.doSomething();
}
```

SendMail Code:

```
public static void doSomething() {
    SendMail.main(new String[] {"main"});
}
```

Nothing seems to work. My SendMail class sends out

```
"Oops something has gone pearshaped!"
```

and

```
07-20 16:32:29.507  11953-11953/blabla.bla I/System.out﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

**SendMail.java**

```
import...

public class SendMail extends Object {

public static void doSomething(String sUser, String sPass) {
SendMail.main(new String[] {"main"})
}

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    for (String s : args)
        System.out.println(s);
    try{
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); // for gmail use smtp.gmail.com
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("foo@gmail.com", "foo"); } });
        mailSession.setDebug(true); // Enable the debug mode
        Message msg = new MimeMessage( mailSession );
        //--[ Set the FROM, TO, DATE and SUBJECT fields
        msg.setFrom( new InternetAddress( "foo@gmail.com " ) );
        msg.setRecipients( Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("1111111111@messaging.sprintpcs.com") );
        msg.setSentDate( new Date());
        msg.setSubject( "Hello World!" );
        //--[ Create the body of the mail
        msg.setText( "Hello from my first e-mail sent with JavaMail" );
        //--[ Ask the Transport class to send our mail message
        Transport.send( msg );
    }catch(Exception E){
        System.out.println( "Oops something has gone pearshaped!");
        System.out.println( E );
        return;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a NetworkOnMainThreadException because you're attempting to do a network operation in the Main UI Thread.

In Android all network operations must be executed in a background Thread.

One way to do it would be to use an AsyncTask with just a `doInBackground()` method, something like this:

```
public class SendMail extends Object {

    public void doSomething(String sUser, String sPass) {
        new SendMailAsync().execute(sUser, sPass);

    }

    class SendMailAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            String username = params[0];
            String password = params[1]

            for (String s : args)
                System.out.println(s);
            try{
                Properties props = new Properties();
                props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); // for gmail use smtp.gmail.com
                props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                props.put("mail.debug", "true");
                props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
                props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
                Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("foo@gmail.com", "foo"); } });
                mailSession.setDebug(true); // Enable the debug mode
                Message msg = new MimeMessage( mailSession );
                //--[ Set the FROM, TO, DATE and SUBJECT fields
                msg.setFrom( new InternetAddress( "foo@gmail.com " ) );
                msg.setRecipients( Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("1111111111@messaging.sprintpcs.com") );
                msg.setSentDate( new Date());
                msg.setSubject( "Hello World!" );
                //--[ Create the body of the mail
                msg.setText( "Hello from my first e-mail sent with JavaMail" );
                //--[ Ask the Transport class to send our mail message
                Transport.send( msg );
            }catch(Exception E){
                System.out.println( "Oops something has gone pearshaped!");
                System.out.println( E );
                return null;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

When you need to call it, instantiate an object first:

```
SendMail sendMail = new SendMail();
sendMail.doSomething(username, password);
```

Comment: Brilliant!! Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

```
  String[] yourArgumentsForSendMailMain = new String[] {"argument"};
  SendMail.main(yourArgumentsForSendMailMain);
```

should work. if not, can you tell me what line is causing the exception? (i.e: step through the try block with debugger until you find the problem line)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you take the whole code from your main method and put it into a non-static run method?

```
void run(String[] args) {
    YOUR CODE HERE
}
```

and when you use this method in another class like

```
SendMail sm = new SendMail();
sm.run(new String[] {"xyz"});
```

you can even use non-private attributes in the other class...